# Compare two csv files and add columns that are not common in both of them

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have to CSV files Book1 and Book2. The columns in Book1 are `A, B, C, D, E` and in Book2 are `A, B, E, H.` 
I want to modify Book2 in such a way that it contains only those column names that are common with Book1 plus whatever additional is there in Book1. The files are :

Book1

```
A           B   C   D   E
10.12.0.1   a   35  0   11
10.12.0.1   b   35  1   10
107.77.87   a   35  0   101
```

Book2:

```
A          B    E   H
9.81.2     b    10  w
10.15.32   b    100 w
11.16.5    b    101 w
```

After modification the final Book2 will be:
Book2_final:

```
A          B    C   D   E
9.81.2     b            10
10.15.32   b            100
11.16.5    b            101
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas
a= open('input_test.txt','r')
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('Book2.csv',dtype='unicode')
inserted_cols = a.read().split(',')
csv1[inserted_cols].to_csv('Book2_test.csv',index=False)
```

where the file `'input_test.txt'` contains the columns of Book1 in the same order sepaated by commas. But I get error:

```
KeyError: "['C' 'D' 'E\\n'] not in index"
```

Can't figure out what's wrong.New to Python.

Comment: You don't want any of the records (IP addrs) in Book1 to be in the Book2_final? Where are you getting the values for column E to put in Book2_final if they don't exist in Book1?

Comment: @aneroid, Book2 will not take any values from Book1. I just need the additional column names in Book1 to be in Book2 and remove whatever extra column name is there in Book2.,in this case column H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reindex` on `book2`'s columns with `book1`'s columns.  You'll have to transpose first, then transpose back.

```
book2.T.reindex(book1.columns).T
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. Tried it on a file with 1000 columns. Its efficient